# bs4 the second comment <!-- > is missing

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am doing python challenge level-9 with BeautifulSoup. 
url = "http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/return/good.html".
bs4.**version** == '4.3.2'.
There are two comments in its page source. The output of soup should be as follows. 
However, when BeautifulSoup is applied, the second comment is missing.

It seems kinda weird. Any hint? Thanks!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/return/good.html"
page = requests.get(url, auth = ("huge", "file")).text
print page
soup = BeautifulSoup(page) 
print soup
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beautiful Soup is a wrapper around an html parser. The default parser is very strict, and when it encounters malformed html silently drops the elements it had trouble with.

You should instead install the package 'html5lib' and use that as your parser, like so:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html5lib')
```